# Does anyone have a driver for fortran DAE solver - COLDAE?

Tags: fortran, collocation, dae

Coldae is a solver writter by U Ascher and R Spiteri, located here http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~ascher/coldae.f .

It can solve upto index-2 DAEs using collocation.

I am new to Fortran, and having a hard time writing the driver, which is a collection of subroutines that define the function, jacobian, boundary conditions, guesses etc.

An example of what I need: https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/colnew/colnew_prb.f . A solved sample problem for an older solver called "COLNEW" by the same author.

Comment: Are you willing to consider other BVP software? If so, what is the equation you are trying to solve and what are your criteria for the software?

Comment: @BillGreene : We are trying to test this specific package. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At line 473 of the source code you provided :

```
contrl - is the actual driver of the package. This routine contains the strategy for nonlinear equation solving.
```

This code is written in Fortran 77 so you can't take benefit from a module. That means that you probably need to create a main program from scratch, prepare the arguments to call the subroutines you need in a specific order and compiling Coldae with your main together. Consider yourself lucky, the code seems rather well documented.

I can suggest you, at least, to follow Fortran tutorials (there is a good documentation on StackOverflow) and to carefully read the comments in the source code, the authors have also included their references so you should take a look too, you can't hope to understand the code if you don't know where it comes from.

The code gives you quite detailed information about the user subroutines needed in the driver. One possible approach is to choose a simple DAE problem, write the corresponding `fsub`, `dfsub` etc., and then insert them in the main subroutine (your driver).

Also, have a look at [this example](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jcash/BVP_software/readme.php) (note that the software they use is different but the user subroutines are very similar to those used by COLDAE).

```
C     *************    user supplied subroutines   *************
C
C
C     the following subroutines must be declared external in the
C     main program which calls coldae.
C
C
C     fsub  - name of subroutine for evaluating f(x,z(u(x)),y(x)) =
C                               t
C             (f ,...,f        )  at a point x in (aleft,aright). 
C               1      ncomp+ny
C
C     dfsub - name of subroutine for evaluating the jacobian of
C             f(x,z(u),y) at a point x.  
C
C     gsub  - name of subroutine for evaluating the i-th component of
C             g(x,z(u(x))) = g (zeta(i),z(u(zeta(i)))) at a point x =
C                             i
C             zeta(i) where 1.le.i.le.mstar. 
C
C     dgsub - name of subroutine for evaluating the i-th row of
C             the jacobian of g(x,z(u(x))).  
C
C     guess - name of subroutine to evaluate the initial
C             approximation for  z(u(x)), y(x) and for dmval(u(x))= vector
C             of the mj-th derivatives of u(x). 
C
C**********************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But I guess, what I am looking for is an example main program, and specifically the subroutines, `fsub`, `dfsub`, `gsub`, `dgsub` etc. that are passed as arguments to `coldae`. I may have been wrong in calling it a 'driver'. I am getting familiar with the fortran syntax, its the `coldae` notation/conventions, that I am finding cryptic to decode.

Comment: @ChintanPathak have a look at [this example](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jcash/BVP_software/readme.php) (added this info to Coriolis' answer but my edit is not yet public). Note that they use a different software (`TWPBVP`) but the user subroutines are very similar to those used in `COLDAE`.